# rails 3 console error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have got this error message when using rails3 consol

> irb(main):018:0> WebtrisulMenu.find(1)
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
>
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in`method_missing'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:299:in `find_one'
>
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:289:in`find_with_ids'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
>
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:444:in`find'
>       from (irb):18
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
>
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in`start'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
>
>       from script/rails:6:in`require'
>       from script/rails:6:in `'

But using like this ,its working fine

> irb(main):019:0> WebtrisulContext.find(:all,:conditions=>['id =1'])
>   => WebtrisulContext id: 1, name: "Primary", internal_name: "", description: "The default Web Trisul context", slinkname: "root_ctx0", webtrisul_dashboard_id: nil

please help me to get out of this?

Comment: can you post your **Gemfile** and **WebtrisulMenu** model source code?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your `WebtrisulMenu` class. It's not getting initialized when Rails environment is loaded as the nilclass error tells me.

Therefore, You are unable to do find on the `WebtrisulMenu` model.

See for anything wrong in this model, and if you can't figure it out yourself, post the contents of the file here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  This in my model                       `class WebtrisulMenu < ActiveRecord::Base  
    establish_connection(  
        "adapter"   => "sqlite3",  
        "database"  => "db/webtrisul.db",
        "timeout"   => 2000  
    )
    set_primary_key :id 
end '

Comment: @Dhinesh: Also post the contents of `WebtrisulContext` model file.  As you are trying to setup your own Sqlite connection, did you check to see if the connection is being set properly.